# How to generate consistent GUID using wix harvest tool

Tags: wix, guid, wix3.7

I am new to using WiX so this my be a dumb question. I am trying to keep the GUID generated by the harvest tool (heat.exe) consistent for files that I am packaging. Everyone seems to say that as long as the file path and sub path remain same heat.exe will generate the same GUID for a file. Unfortunately, I am not seeing that behavior. My workflow is as follows.

Copy all the deliverable files to a staging directory during my build process. Then run heat.exe in the staging directory to generate the component fragment wxs file. Before I copy the file into the staging directory I clear all my old files.

I want to add the generated wxs file into my source control so that I can achieve minor upgrades. If my understanding is correct for me to achieve that I need to have consistent GUID across my builds so that I can track them.

The command line I use for generating the wxs file is as follows:-

```
c:\foobar\build\>C:\win32\wix-3.7.1224.0\heat.exe dir . -cg MyCG -dr INSTALLDIR -g1 -gg -nologo -sreg -suid -t C:\foobar\src\support\packaging\wix\foo.xslt -var var.foobarSource -out c:\foobar\src\support\packaging\wix\foo.wxs
```

What I see that the GUID generated are different during each run. Is there was a way for me to keep GUID consistent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should specify `-ag` flag.

```
-ag
Auto generate component guids at compile time, e.g. set Guid="*".
```

As long as your file paths are the same, generated GUID's will be the same for files.

Comment: Does this mean that I should remove the -gg option which implies generate guid now and use -ag instead.

Comment: If I use -ag flag is there way for me to list what the generated GUID were at compile time to verify that they remain the same.

Comment: Yes. -ag flag is used if you want to do minor upgrades. If you have used previously -gg flag, then switching to -ag flag wont help you anymore(if that's the case; you could write custom tool that processes your wxs to keep GUIDS consistent - you can read everything from MSI file). Note that Guid="*" on Component wont produce Guid randomly - it is calculated from the path. If you want to verify things, you should set up test environment and see how minor upgrades work.

Comment: Would the guids change if the top level path name changes. I mean if I am currently generating guids for a build directory c:\foo\build and it changes to c:\bar\build

Comment: No. The guids are fixed within the INSTALLATION dir, not the source one. Unless you change the place/folder where the files are installed on client's computer, they will be same.